# Xamarin Android - Sharing Image from app results in no image showing, and IO Error in Outlook for Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I'm attempting to create a function which allow me to share be able to share an image through androids share dialogue, into any supporting application eg. Slack, Outlook, etc.

However when I run the code below which completes without error the image does not appear in any application I share to and Outlook fro android gives a generic IO error.

```
async void shareMetricFromURL(){
                WebClient webClient = new WebClient ();
                var url = new Uri ("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/02/Stack_Overflow_logo.svg/500px-Stack_Overflow_logo.svg.png");
                byte[] bytes = null;


                try{
                    bytes = await webClient.DownloadDataTaskAsync(url);
                }
                catch(TaskCanceledException){
                    return;
                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    return;
                }

                string documentsPath = Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryPictures).ToString();
                string localFilename = "downloaded.png";
                string localPath = System.IO.Path.Combine (documentsPath, localFilename);

                //Sive the Image using writeAsync
                FileStream fs = new FileStream (localPath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
                await fs.WriteAsync (bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

                fs.Close ();

                var sendIntent = new Intent();
                sendIntent.SetAction(Intent.ActionSend);

                var uri = Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(new Java.IO.File(localPath));
                sendIntent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraStream, uri);

                sendIntent.SetType("image/*");
                StartActivityForResult(Intent.CreateChooser(sendIntent, "Share With..."), 0);
    }
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Try Adding

```
 sendIntent.AddFlags (ActivityFlags.GrantReadUriPermission);
```

So the file can be readable

See this example

```
public void Send()
{


    Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(Resources,Resource.Drawable.icon_120);

    var tempFilename = "test.png";
    var sdCardPath = Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath;
    var filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(sdCardPath, tempFilename);
    using (var os = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
    {
        b.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 100, os);
    }
    b.Dispose ();

    var imageUri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse ($"file://{sdCardPath}/{tempFilename}");
    var sharingIntent = new Intent ();
    sharingIntent.SetAction (Intent.ActionSend);
    sharingIntent.SetType ("image/*");

    sharingIntent.PutExtra (Intent.ExtraStream, imageUri);
    sharingIntent.AddFlags (ActivityFlags.GrantReadUriPermission);
    StartActivity (Intent.CreateChooser (sharingIntent, "choose"));}
```